# Can a Javascript literal object fire events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, object-literal

I  have a Javascript object literal:

```
var Toolbar = {

    init: function(toolbar) {
        this.Bar = $(toolbar); // scope is Toolbar object literal

        this.Bar.find('clearButton').click(function() {
            this.trigger('clear'); // doesn't work!
            this.Bar.trigger('clear'); // works!
    }
}

Toolbar.init($('div.toolbar'));
Toolbar.bind('clear', function() { ... }); // doesn't work!
Toolbar.Bar.bind('clear', function() { ... }); // works!
```

I'd like to be able to trigger the `clear` event on the Toolbar object literal rather than the toolbar DOM object referenced in the literal. Is this possible, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Shouldn't something be passed to `init`? Anyway, I think the error messages should be fairly clear about "why it doesn't work". At the very least, *include them in the post*.

Comment: Corrected my question, I forgot to include the the jQuery object in the `init()` call. And when I say 'doesn't work', what I mean is that an object literal doesn't look like it can fire events (which kind of makes sense, since it's not a DOM object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var Toolbar = {

    init: function(toolbar) {
        this.Bar = $(toolbar); // scope is Toolbar object literal

        this.Bar.find('.clearButton').click($.proxy(function() {
            $(this).trigger('clear'); // should work now
            this.Bar.trigger('clear'); // still works
        }, this));
    }
};

Toolbar.init($('div.toolbar'));

$(Toolbar).bind('clear', function() { 
    console.log('Toolbar'); 
}); // should work now

Toolbar.Bar.bind('clear', function() { 
    console.log('Toolbar.Bar'); 
}); // still works
```

1. You need to maintain the `this` reference in the click function.  I used `$.proxy`; some folks use `var self = this;`
2. `Toolbar` is not a jQuery object so it should be wrapped in `$()` to access jQuery's functions.  Also wrap the `this` that refers to a `Toolbar` instance in the click function.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? :

```
var Toolbar = {

    init: function(toolbar) {
        this.Bar = $(toolbar); // scope is Toolbar object literal

        this.trigger =
            function() { this.Bar.trigger.apply(this.Bar, arguments); };

        this.bind = function() { this.Bar.bind.apply(this.Bar, arguments); };

        this.Bar.find('clearButton').click(function() {
            this.trigger('clear');
    }
};

Toolbar.init();
Toolbar.bind('clear', function() { ... });
```

If you want, you can readily create a function to handle the wrapping; either of these, as you prefer:

```
function wrapperitize(wrapper, wrappee, method /*, more_methods...*/)
{
    wrapper[method] = function() { wrappee[method].apply(wrappee, arguments); };
    for(var i = 3; i < arguments.length; ++i)
        wrapperitize(wrapper, wrappee, arguments[i]);
}

function wrapperitize(wrapper, wrappeeProp, method /*, more_methods...*/)
{
    wrapper[method] = function()
    {
        wrapper[wrappeeProp][method].apply(wrapper[wrappeeProp], arguments);
    };
    for(var i = 3; i < arguments.length; ++i)
        wrapperitize(wrapper, wrappeeProp, arguments[i]);
}
```

where the former would be called as `wrapperitize(this, this.Bar, 'trigger', 'bind')` and the latter as `wrapperitize(this, 'Bar', 'trigger', 'bind')` (the difference being that the former will make `this` into a wrapper for whatever `this.Bar` currently is, whereas the latter will make `this` into a wrapper for whatever `this.Bar` might ever become in the future.

(Note, by the way, the tiny bit of recursion. This is to avoid problematic variable capture, due to the way closures work in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call a method on the `Toolbar` object, you'll need to define it there. If you don't need to add very many of those methods this way, you can just define each of them in the Toolbar object itself:

```
var Toolbar = {
    clear: function() { this.Bar.trigger('clear'); }

    init: function(toolbar) {
        this.Bar = $(toolbar); // scope is Toolbar object literal
        this.Bar.find('clearButton').click(function() {
            this.clear(); 
    }
}
```

However, if you need to call very many of them this will quickly get ugly. If you *really* want to be able to call all of the methods available of the jquery object on the Toolbar object, you could try to loop through all of them with a `for in` loop and add them to the Toolbar object, but this would be tedious, annoying to read, inefficient, and potentially cause some bugs. I would just use `$(toolbar)` whenever you wanted to call a method on that object as it gets rid of all those disadvantages. :D